# Google ask me a USA id card in id verification,but my account are not registed in USA so I have not any id card meet that requirement

Tags: google-play-console

I am a Chinese developer,learning flutter for hobby. Country of my play console account , google account , google payment(CMB American Express® Corporate Card) are all setted/registed to China.

But **google still ask me a USA id card for address and other infomation in verification process**.How to use Chinese id card for it?

Comment: Yeah,I know there is no play store for China.But it's just for hobby .So I am no plan to  use Google's AdMob in China , or Chinese OAID in USA to make some earning(I really hate these).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming problem.

Comment: @Quentin , thanks .I post it on reddit.